# git performances on development machine with multiple users

Tags: git, ssh

We migrated from svn to git.

A project sources are hosted on a development machine. Each user has his own repository on the server mounted with nfs on his machine.
Each user executes git commands after be connected with ssh on the development machine.
It's a bit weird, but for now we can not change that.

So one machine executes a lot of git commands and sometimes freezes on 'git pull' or 'git stash'...
I don't know how to improve this ? Perhaps it's a limit on git threads ?
I don't find anything for that in git documentation.

Thanks you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, we just noticed that some software put a watchdog on the nfs and can locked the directory.
Git was then greatly slowed down / frozen.

Sometimes it is enough to leave the concerned software, sometimes a restart of the user machine is necessary.
This is rare but can happen with a multitude of software: GitKraken, Sublime text, Netbeans ...

Hope it will help someone in the same case.